# Sanitize or escape html tags from user filled forms

Tags: angularjs

I have made forms using html and posting data to backend using angularjs. I want to escape the html tags before posting to backend. How do i do this?

example if user posts like

```
<p> hello world </p>
```

It should be sent to server like

```
&lt;p&gt; hello world &lt;/p&gt;
```

Comment: You shouldn't trust the client side (JS) for this type of task

Answer (score 0):

ngSanitize should do the trick. Please see [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize)

And here's a way to do it from client side.

var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

```
 $scope.htmlText = "<p> Let's see</p>";

  $scope.htmlEncode = function(){
    var safeString = $('<div>').text($scope.htmlText).html();
    // if you don't have jquery the use the following
    //safeString = $scope.htmlText.replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;');//and so on for other html special characters.
    alert(safeString);
  };
}]);
```

See [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eVqmTsKgQBndy3qzLYf1?p=preview)

Comment: i want to escape string when sending to backend.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to post. I am assuming you are expecting html on your input fields, if that is the case [see posted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940681/angularjs-strip-html-filter-on-ng-options)

Answer (score 0):

*(The question was updated in to a different area since the answer)*

Use [PHP Sanitize Filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) in the server side to sanitize user inputs.

Using any sanitation tool in the client side is not recommended since the script can be modified to ignore them by a malicious user.

Comment: - Ideally it should be done at server side. If i want to do on client side. How do i do it?

Comment: Use $sanitize inside a custom form validater.